# Checking device's supported PCM sample rates

Tags: android, audiorecord, sample-rate

I'd like to check whether device supports particular sample rate.

I've tried the following (which should work according http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html#getMinBufferSize(int, int, int) ) but doesn't (it never gets AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE):

```
    int bufferSize8000 = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(90000000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

    if(bufferSize8000 != (AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE | AudioRecord.ERROR ))    {
        Log.v("samplerate", String.valueOf(bufferSize8000));
    } else {

        Log.v("samplerate", "NOTsupported");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE | AudioRecord.ERROR )
```

Means -2 | -1, which equals -1, which equals `AudioRecord.ERROR`, which is why you're never getting the result you expect.

So this

```
if(bufferSize8000 != (AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE | AudioRecord.ERROR ))    {
```

Should be

```
if (bufferSize8000 != Audiorecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE && bufferSize8000 != AudioRecord.ERROR) {
```

Comment: Still the same. For sampe rate 0Hz returns buffer size of 4096.

Comment: Not all vendors care about the sample rate when they calculate the minimum buffer size. Some have a default buffer size, which they might multiply by the number of channels you specify. For example, see [this implementation](https://www.codeaurora.org/gitweb/quic/la/?p=platform/hardware/qcom/audio.git;a=blob;f=alsa_sound/AudioHardwareALSA.cpp;h=b68e25b6ed3f2b830393cb0e850397e44352e9e7;hb=refs/heads/jb_rel_rb1.1#l1322)